# how can I set two different hooks in the style attribute

Tags: javascript, css, hook

This is the HTML part and I want to use two hooks for styling

```
<div className='first ' style={{blacktowhite , borderGoldToOrange}}  >
```

When I am running without the second one the background color changes from black to white,
but when I am adding the second one then page remains black only, how can I fix this?

Hooks is defined this way

```
     const [yelloToblack, setyelloToblack] = useState({})
     // after some if else condition
     if(..)
     setyelloToblack({
                    color : 'black',
                })
     else 
     setyelloToblack({
                    color : '#FFD700',
            })
```

Comment: const [color,blacktowhite]=useState("black")
const [color,borderGoldToOrange]=useState("orange")

<div className='first ' style={{backgroundColor:blacktowhite , boredr:borderGoldToOrange}}  >

Comment: Please see I have edited the answer I have done the same in different way, what I need to change according to above.

Comment: Well, the thing that I found strange is that you pass Object for useState hook.Passing Object as you did will make typescript happy, but now you cheat on yourself as typescript won't guard you.Depending on situation I would suggest to go the first route and leave useState empty, or hardcode to destructure the object first like ...{object}  . second problem is that If the initial state of the state is an empty object then you might get an infinite loop.

Comment: and coming to your question , when you are using setyelloToblack({
 color : 'black',}) that means in your style attribute {{{color:"black"}}} is set . you can destructure it or make the usestate empty with ("")

Comment: The first one will change the background and the second one will change the font color. Will your method still good here?

Comment: second one will change the border color.<div className='first ' style={{backgroundColor:blacktowhite , borderColor:borderGoldToOrange}} >

Comment: Please tag the question with the framework you're using.